# Сумма значений массива php

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется массив, в данном формате:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01.09.2018
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 123
            [3] => 15.5
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 02.09.2018
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 456
        [3] => 25
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 04.09.2018
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 555
        [3] => 78
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 01.07.2018
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 666
        [3] => 2
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10.08.2018
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 748
        [3] => 5
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 17.08.2018
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 155
        [3] => 20
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 13.08.2018
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 748
        [3] => 17.5
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => 02.09.2018
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 124
        [3] => 13
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => 03.09.2018
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 456
        [3] => 5
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => 04.08.2018
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 666
        [3] => 10.5
    )
```

)

Делаю доску почета, внутри массива 2- id пользователя, 3 - к-во набранных баллов.
Необходимо чудесным образом суммировать баллы для каждого пользователя. Каким образом можно это сделать? Шуршал документацию, пробовал различные функции (in_array, array_keys и т.д.) но скорее всего не в том направлении двигаюсь. Кто что скажет?

Comment: Эти данные из БД достаются?

Comment: Вообще эти данные будут браться из csv файла. Но затем стучаться в бд и по ид (с наибольшими значениями)вытягивать остальные данные.

Comment: Если бы брались с БД, то можно было б агрегацию на уровне запроса сделать

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$data = [];
foreach ($array as $val) {
    if (!array_key_exists($val[2], $data) {
        $data[$val[2]] = 0;
    }
    $data[$val[2]] += $val[3];
}
```

Comment: Кто ставит минусы, обоснуйте

Answer (score -1):

Можно вот так:

```
$results = [];

foreach($array as $item){
    $results[$item[2]] += $item[3];
}
```

В качестве индекса массива вставляем айди пользоваетеля, и плюсуем ему баллы.

Answer (score -1):

Используйте лучше phpшную функцию array_sum, будет в разы быстрее работать чем примеры выше)

Вот описание функции: http://php.net/array_sum

Comment: Мне не нужно все элементы плюсовать, а каждый ид отдельно.