# Сложить свойства объектов в массиве с одинаковым ключом

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется массив:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 2018,6,02
        [1] => 0.56
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 2018,6,04
        [1] => 0.56
    ) 
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => 2018,6,04
        [1] => 2.29
    ) 
    [3] => Array (
        [0] => 2018,7,22
        [1] => 276.03
    ) 
    [4] => Array (
        [0] => 2018,7,23
        [1] => 276.03
    ) 
    [5] => Array (
        [0] => 2018,7,23
        [1] => 326.86
    ) 
    [6] => Array (
        [0] => 2018,7,27
        [1] => 328.33
    )
)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы если есть в массиве та же дата, то произошло их объединение? Например:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 2018,6,02 
        [1] => 0.56
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 2018,6,04
        [1] => 2,85
    ) 
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => 2018,7,22 
        [1] => 276.03
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [0] => 2018,7,23 
        [1] => 602,89
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [0] => 2018,7,27 
        [1] => 328.33
    )
)
```

Comment: А в чём проблема? Прогоняете в цикле массив. При прогонке добавляете этот элемент в результирующий массив, если там такого элемента нет. Если есть, то приплюсовываете второй элемент ячейки к второму элементу ячейки итогового массива.

Comment: можете в ответе зделать ето  на данную примере

Comment: Соседний вопрос о том же https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/877264/%d0%a1%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-php

Comment: ето другой вопрос

Comment: Его суть та же - посчитать сумму чего либо с одинаковым значением.

Comment: Если данные выбираются с БД, то можно на уровне запроса агрегацию сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            $data = [];
            foreach($array as $b){
                $data[$b[0]] = isset($data[$b[0]]) ? $data[$b[0]] + $b[1] : $b[1];
            }
            print_r($data);
```

вот вам ответ

Comment: Для чего вы используете `die`?